# cell order change while tableview scrolls up and down

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am doing one registration form for iphone application. In that am having one tableview with four section.In last section am having one row with register button.I got the tableview with data well.But while scrolling the tableview up and down my register button goes to 2nd section.I added the code below.What wrong i did in this.Help me to solve.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
  {
    // static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       NSString *identifier = @"reuseIdentifier";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    NSLog(@" row and  section =====  %d,%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section);
    if(indexPath.section != 3)
    {
        UILabel *lbl_title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(isiPad?CGRectMake(7,10,250,50):CGRectMake(70,40,340, 35))];
        [lbl_title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:(isiPad?20:13)]];
        lbl_title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [lbl_title setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        lbl_title.tag = ((indexPath.section+1)*10)+indexPath.row;
        //NSLog(@"lbl data tag   %d",lbl_title.tag);

        lbl_title.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_title];    

        UILabel *lbl_data = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(isiPad?CGRectMake(260,10,410,50):CGRectMake(70,40,340, 35))];
        [lbl_data setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:(isiPad?20:13)]];
        lbl_data.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];//25-25-112
        [lbl_data setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:25.0/255.0 green:25.0/255.0 blue:112.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        lbl_data.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        lbl_data.tag = ((indexPath.section+1)*100)+indexPath.row;
        //NSLog(@"lbl data tag   %d,%@",lbl_data.tag,lbl_data);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl_data];  

        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            if(indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"Email";
            }
            else if(indexPath.row == 1)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"Password";

            }
            else if(indexPath.row == 2)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"Confirm password";
            }
        }
        else if(indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            if(indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"First name";
            }
            else if(indexPath.row == 1)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"Last name";

            }
            else if(indexPath.row == 2)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"Nickname";
            }
            else if(indexPath.row == 3)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"Gender";
            }            
        }
        else if(indexPath.section == 2)
        {
            if(indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"City";
            }
            else if(indexPath.row == 1)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"State";

            }
            else if(indexPath.row == 2)
            {
                lbl_title.text = @"Country";
            }
        }

    }
    if(indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:165.0/255.0 green:42.0/255.0 blue:42.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];//165-42-42
      UIButton *btn_register = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:isiPad?CGRectMake(10,0,660,70):CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
        [btn_register addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_register_clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn_register setTitle:@"Register" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //btn_register.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
         btn_register.backgroundColor =  [UIColor blueColor];
        [btn_register setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn_register setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Bold" size:24]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn_register];
        }
    }

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"updating cell.........");
} 
  return cell;

  }
```

[image: before scrolling up and down]

[image: after scrolling]

Comment: see my answer .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353280/when-tableview-scroll-than-value-changed/14353299#14353299

Comment: my another answer with same issue which you phase from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702242/uitableviewcells-with-default-image-overwritten-with-other-images-upon-scrolli/15702271#15702271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets repeated because you added it to a cell's contentview, and then you re-use that cell.
Rather than adding it in cell's contentView, add the button as a cell accessory.

```
cell.accessoryView = btn_register;
```

And in all other cells, set accessoryView to nil.

```
cell.accessoryView = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try setting different identifiers for each section of cells. You can also use Use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

Using a different cell identifier for the "Register" cell should work. And your code will be much clear if you use a container to hold the data, like an `NSDictionary`. For example:

```
NSArray *account = @[@"Email", @"Password", @"Confirm password"];
NSArray *userInfo = @[@"First name", @"Last name", @"Gender", @"Nickname"];
// ...
NSDictionary *data = @{@"Account": account, @"User Information": userInfo /* ... */};
```